# Curtain.js effect not working after launching single page website

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, single-page-application, jquery-effects

The curtain.js effect (jQuery plugin) on my single page website (www[.]webmill[.]eu) went dead after I launched the website. When I click the menu items on the initial website view nothing happens and you can't scroll to them either. On mobile display everything seems to be working according to plan:

```
function triggerAnimation(){
    if(MQ == 'desktop') {
        //if on desktop screen - animate sections
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? animateSection() : window.requestAnimationFrame(animateSection);
    } else {
        //on mobile - remove the style added by jQuery 
        $('.section').find('.container-fluid').removeAttr('style').find('.half').removeAttr('style');
    }
    //update navigation arrows visibility
    checkNavigation();
}
```

In general it's meant to behave like this: http://goo.gl/UxTmw3
Until recently was believing it was responsive design related but research turned out otherwise and so far nothing has done the trick.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its relative but you have a javascript error

> Error: There are multiple templates named 'velvet'. Each template needs a unique name.

Comment: Thanks!  but still, even if there is an error,  how to explain that it works fine on other platforms with smaller screens and not on a large one?

Comment: I thought maybe this was creating your problem.
I also cant find a container class in your html. Only container-fluid

Comment: You use .container for a responsive fixed width container and .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport (as documented by Bootstrap). Tried changing but didn't solve the issue. so far it looks like it's linked to screen resolution. It stops working as intended from 1170px width

Comment: after enough juggling with responsiveness, I am now pretty sure it is javascript related since the curtain.js effect (jQuery plugin) it's meant to have on the sections and when you scroll is dead. This is how it's meant to act: http://goo.gl/UxTmw3  have been looking at how to fix this but haven't come up with anything so far (idioteque - thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction!)